# Service Worker does not successfully serve the manifest's start_url

Tags: android, service, manifest, progressive-web-apps, worker

Completely new at this, so please take it easy on me! :)

I am trying to figure out a way to be able to add my web page to home screen in android. I have understood that I had to use a service worker and a manifest to do so.

But when I have installed and registered my service worker, it won't fetch my manifest!

> Error: Service Worker does not successfully serve the manifest's start_url

Here is my sw.js:

```
// Chrome's currently missing some useful cache methods,
// this polyfill adds them.
importScripts('serviceworker-cache-polyfill.js');

// Here comes the install event!
// This only happens once, when the browser sees this
// version of the ServiceWorker for the first time.
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  // We pass a promise to event.waitUntil to signal how 
  // long install takes, and if it failed
  event.waitUntil(
    // We open a cache…
    caches.open('simple-sw-v1').then(function(cache) {
      // And add resources to it
      return cache.addAll([
        './',
        'style.css',
        'logging.js'
      ]);
    })
  );
});

// The fetch event happens for the page request with the
// ServiceWorker's scope, and any request made within that page
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  // Calling event.respondWith means we're in charge
  // of providing the response. We pass in a promise
  // that resolves with a response object
  event.respondWith(
    // First we look for something in the caches that matches the request
    caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
      // If we get something, we return it, otherwise
      // it's null, and we'll pass the request to
      // fetch, which will use the network.
      return response || fetch(event.request);
    })
  );
});
```

And here is my manifest.json:

```
{
  "short_name": "Ferie Med Mening",
  "name": "Ferie Med Mening",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "https://feriemedmening.xyz/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/ikon-1.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "48x48"
    },
    {
      "src": "https://feriemedmening.xyz/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/ikon-1.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "96x96"
    },
    {
      "src": "https://feriemedmening.xyz/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/ikon-1.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "https://feriemedmening.xyz/"
  "score_url": "https://feriemedmening.xyz/"
  "theme_color": "#2ABB9C"
}
```

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Is this PWA related? If so, please tag that.